# Comparar dos arrays y guardar valor que se repite en otro arreglo

Tags: c#, array

Estoy intentando comparar 2 arreglos (`a` y `b` respectivamente) y el valor que de `a` que se repita en `b` que forme otro vector.

Le he planteado de esta manera: cuando deseo comparar los valores ingresado en `b` con `a` me sale error y no puedo entender como solucionarlo.

```
int[] a = new int[2];
int[] b = new int[2];
int[] c = new int[2];
int n = 0, m = 0, i, k, l=0;

for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero vector A");
    a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


}

for (k= 0; k < b.Length; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero vector B");
    b[k] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //Comparo el valor de b que estoy guardando con la posicion de a. si es correcto se guarda en el vector c
    if (b[k] == a[i])
        {

            b[k] = c[l];

            Console.WriteLine("C: " + c[l]);
        }

}
```

Comment: Tu error lo tienes en if (b[k] == a[i]) ya que al salir del bucle anterior i se queda con valor 2 y el vector a solo llega hasta a[1], estás intentando acceder a una posición que no existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIENES 2 ERRORES:

1. **if (b[k] == a[i])**
2. **b[k] = c[l]**

El primer error lo tienes en el 2do `for(k= 0; k < b.Length; k++){...}` aquí estás realizando la siguiente comprobación `if (b[k] == a[i])` y te falla.

El problema está donde b[0] y b[1] tendrán los valores establecidos por el usuario, a[i] no existe ya que la i se evalúa siempre como un 2 y se sale del array, estando los valores reales en a[0], a[1] esto es por declarar la i como global y realizar un último i++ al salir del primer bucle for(){}.

El segundo error lo tienes al imprimir el resultado c[l], en tu caso l siempre es 0 ya que no cambias el valor, y tampoco le asignas ningún elemento c[l]=..., estos dos errores provocan que nunca puedas mostrar los resultados de elementos iguales encontrados en ambos arrays.

Solución remplazar el segundo for por:

```
for (k= 0; k < b.Length; k++){
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero vector B");
    b[k] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())

    //PARA CADA VALOR DE B vas a buscar si existe en a.
    for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        if (b[k] == a[i]){
              c[l] = b[k];
              Console.WriteLine("C: " + c[l]);
              l++; 
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias UHDante. Me ayudo a reforzar tu aporte. Saludos !

Answer (score 5):

Para ampliar las respuestas que te han dado, C# y en concreto Linq dispone del método [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) que hace exactamente lo que estás buscando. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
int[] arrayA = new int[] { 3, 4,6, 7, 9 };
int[] arrayB = new int[] { 1, 2,3, 7, 8 };

var resArray = arrayA.Intersect(arrayB).ToArray();
//en resArray nos devuelve {3,7}
```

Comment: Gracias Pikoh por tu respuesta. Si, contemple esa opcion pero lo que busco es la forma con los for anidados. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Te voy a explicar lo que estas haciendo, primero rellenas un array a, hasta ahi todo correcto, pero despues, mientras rellenas el b, estas comparando que ese numero que acabas de ingresar es igual a a[i], es decir, al ultimo numero del array a, ya que i, lo tienes definido como variable global arriba y al acabar el bucle for, i sera igual a la longitud de array a, es decir, siempre va a ser 2, por ejemplo, siempre comparas los numeros que recien ingresas en b con el ultimo de a. Y despues, si esa condicion se cumple, metes ese valor siempre en c[l], y si l es igual a 0 y nunca la cambiar, siempre vas a estar reemplazando el primer valor del array c.

Te arreglo un poco tu código.

```
    int[] a = new int[2];
    int[] b = new int[2];
    int[] c = new int[2];
    int n = 0, m = 0, i, k, l=0;

    for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero vector A");
        a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (k= 0; k < b.Length; k++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero vector B");
        b[k] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Aqui esta el error, justo despues de guardar un numero b le 
        //comparas solo con el ultimo de a siempre

        //Es necesario hacer otro bucle for aqui que recorra a para comparar 
        //el nuevo numero de b con todos los de a

        //Reseteamos i = 0 y repetimos bucle para que recorra a
        for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            //Ahora si estamos comparando el nuevo numero de b con 
            //todos los de a, ya que i ahora cambia gracias al bucle nuevo
            if (b[k] == a[i])
            {
                //El segundo problema esta aqui, l es siempre 0, hay que 
                //incrementar l cada vez que se guarda un nuevo valor
                b[k] = c[l];

                //Incremento en 1 el valor de l para que el proximo 
                //valor se guarde en la siguiente posicion vacia del array
                l++;

                Console.WriteLine("C: " + c[l]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Cobas. Eso es que exactamente esta buscando. Gracias por despejarme las duda.  De todos modos cuando entra a comparar en el ultimo valor ingresado me dice que esta fuera de indice. Intente agregarle un lugar mas al vector (cuando compara) pero no hay forma. no se que estoy haciendo mal. gracias.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el nuevo código actualizado y marcalo para saber cual es el de la pregunta original y el que te ha quedado y asi puedo verlo y decirte jeje. De nada